# How can I get the collapse panel to work?

Tags: reactjs, codepen

I am using reactbootstrap and tried to create this codepen to get it working but no luck sofar. This is the panel that is supposed to open and close:

```
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Fade} from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Collapse } from 'react-bootstrap';
    class App extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {};
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <Button onClick={ ()=> this.setState({ open: !this.state.open })}>
              click
            </Button>
            <Collapse in={this.state.open}>
              <div>
                <Well>
                  Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid.
                  Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident.
                </Well>
              </div>
            </Collapse>
          </div>
        );
      }

    };
```

This is the [codepen](http://codepen.io/gekkerkanniet/pen/RorjQq?editors=1111)
There are no errors in the console so have no clue what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So few mistakes that you did while implementing the codepen.

1. You need to import `bootstrap.min.css` and `bootstrap.min.js` in your html in order to use `react-bootstrap`
2. You did not import the `Well` component
3. If you are trying to do this in codepen you shouldn't import your components like

   ```
   import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
   import { Panel } from 'react-bootstrap';
   import { Fade} from 'react-bootstrap';
   import { Collapse } from 'react-bootstrap';
   import {Well} from 'react-bootstrap';
   ```

instead you should import them like

```
    var Button = ReactBootstrap.Button;
    var Panel = ReactBootstrap.Panel;
    var Fade = ReactBootstrap.Fade;
    var Collapse = ReactBootstrap.Collapse;
    var Well = ReactBootstrap.Well;
```

[Codepen Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MbKrmr?editors=1111)

Comment: @bierhier Sorry wrong demo url added. Updated it just now

Comment: do you know how to ensure content does not get pushed down   that is under the panel?

Comment: I don't understand what you meant. Can you explain it in more detail

Comment: okay I understand now, I think you need to define a fixed position css to the content under it.

Comment: What style class makes the text invisble inside the Collapse? because when  paste this in my app it is still visible?

Comment: Do you mean it is not toggling, like it is in codepen

Comment: yes it is moving but does not hide the text in the panel

Comment: Are you sure you have included bootstrap.css and bootstrap.js along with jquery in your index.html

Comment: O good point, still have the content below pushing down though. How do I fix this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6037317/make-a-div-slide-down-without-pushing-content-down  Try to follow this or make your div below to have position: fixed and top: 10px; etc